# CodeIgniter setting userdata session

Tags: codeigniter, session

Hi guys having a bit of a problem with setting userdata to true, maybe someone on here can help me out?

I am using codeigniter

here is my controller where I set the userdata and redirect forward to another controller "site" and call the function members_area

```
    if($query) // if the users pass/user is right
    {
        $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'is_logged_in' => true      
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('site/members_area');
    }
    else{
    $this->index(); 

    }
```

Then this is my site controller:

```
function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();
}

function members_area()
{

    $this->load->view('members_area');
}

function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if(!isset($is_logged_in) ||  $is_logged_in != true)
    {
        echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page. <a href="../login">Login</a>';
        die();

    }

}
```

What do you guys reckon? Much appreciated!

Comment: so what happend ? please tell in details

Comment: It still says I dont have permission after sucecssfully logging in and being redirected to the members_area

Comment: Have you added $this->load->library('session'); in your site controller anywhere (preferably constructor) ?

Comment: I am autoloading session in the config, although have tried loading it your way aswell and still the same

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by setting `$config['cookie_secure']   = FALSE;` in the autoload.php in config folder, as it was TRUE before to secure cookies, any insight on why might be great? but this fixed the problem :)

Comment: If its set to true, cookies will only be set if a secure connection exists i.e. when your website is running on HTTPS.